# Spring Security framework JDBC query

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application with PostgreSQL as database. I have a table in database named 'registration', and trying to see if the username and password entered in database matches of what user entered. I am getting PostGres error. I am assigning role in model itself right now, as mentioned below :

Defining role in model :

```
 class User {
        private static final GrantedAuthority USER_AUTH = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
private String Username;
private String password;
private String role="ROLE_USER";
    @Transient
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    public User() {
            this.authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(USER_AUTH);
    }
 public User(String Username, String password, String Role){
        this.Username = Username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = Role;

    }

    }
```

Error code :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select username,password from registration where username=?]; The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:787)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:151)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkColumnIndex(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2866)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkResultSet(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2883)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getBoolean(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1989)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getBoolean(DelegatingResultSet.java:216)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getBoolean(DelegatingResultSet.java:216)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl$1.mapRow(JdbcDaoImpl.java:196)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl$1.mapRow(JdbcDaoImpl.java:192)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:708)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
```

Security-applicationContext.xml

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider >
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username,password
                from registration where username=?" authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, r.Role from registration where u.username=?" />
          </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Note : I have Role saved in the same table as user.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a `JdbcDaoImpl`, the `usersByUsernameQuery` must return 3 parameters : username, password, and enabled, and you query only returns 2, so the error. Your query should be :

```
select username,password,true from registration where username=?
```

And your `authorities-by-username-query` is also incorrect. I cannot be sure without knowing how is declared `registration` table, but I guess it should be :

```
select username, role from registration where username=?
```

Comment: Thank you. I made that change. Is the 2nd part of query correct, as my role is in the same table as my user information is? How should I check if this user has the right username and password to validate?

Comment: For your 2nd question, Spring security checks the password for you. For the 1st part, your request is wrong. See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I have declared both username and role as Varchar in registration table. And as String in my User class. Now when I am trying to authenticate, the role is getting passed as null. But as you can see from the first line of my class, I am granting ROLE_USER. I am adding User class in main question. Kindly have a look.

Comment: You only grant ROLE_USER when you use empty constructor. If you want to assign ROLE_USER if you get nothing from your request (role == NULL in `registration` table), add `if ((role == null) || role.isEmpty()) {role = "ROLE_USER"; }` at the end of the 3 arguments constructor.